# Extreme beginner having issues with print and def

Tags: python, function, printing

I bought a course for Python and I am already having issues in the 1st assignment.
I am supposed to print something like:

```
color = ___
thing = ___
print (color + " is the color of " + thing)
```

The desired result would be "Yellow is the color of sunshine", but when I just substitute the ___ with the words I want, it tells me I did not "define", the problem is all the previous videos that lead to this assignment never even mentioned def as a function. It never went past printing stuff and doing simple maths exercises with Python. I am a bit lost, please help me out and thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you write something akin to ``color = word`` or ``color = "word"``?

Comment: Strings are defined between quotes `color = "Yellow"`

Answer (score 5):

`Yellow` is a variable with the name Yellow. `"Yellow"` (note the quotes) is a string containing the text Yellow.

So `color = Yellow` tries to assign to color a value from a variable (Yellow) that doesn't exist.

`color = "Yellow"` does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ok nevermind, I believe I have found the answer, I should have wrote the first 2 lines like this:

```
color = "Yellow"
```

Without the "" it gave me error but as soon as I included them I got it right. Thank you

Comment: When you figure out your own problem make sure to accept your answer. I believe that there is a wait time though.

Answer (score 0):

You should define color string(like in my code below) and I would suggest using formatted string.

Code:-

```
color = "XYZ"
thing = "XYZ"

print (f'{color} is color of {thing}')
```